# Имя класса для hasMany и hasOne Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Имеются два геттера связей в контроллере

```
 public function getCreator() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'creator']);
}

public function getPhotos() {
    return $this->hasMany(Photo::className(), ['id' => 'photoid'])->viaTable('{{photolist}}', ['adid' => 'id']);
}
```

Однако в первом случае User::className() (хоть и устаревший, но всё же его использовать легче всего) отрабатывает, а во втором Photo::className() выдает ошибку неизвестного метода className.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Добрый день. Замените className() на просто class

Comment: Да, PHPStorm почему-то подчеркивает его как ошибку "Версия PHP должна быть 5.5", а у меня 7.0.4. Это вроде бы заработало. Однако, теперь в BaseActiveRecord в методе createRelationParty ошибка. Не может использовать $query = $class::find(); (судя по всему, не может создать адекватную связь).

Comment: это зависит от версии yii2, если старше 2.0.13, то className() будет отмечен как устаревший

Answer (score 0):

В PHPStorm поменял версию PHP в настройках на 7.0, теперь class не подчеркивается.
Забыл наследовать у модели ActiveRecord.